# Get execution time of command which has output to /dev/null

Tags: bash, time

I'm trying to get real time (in seconds) of a command execution, but without printing command output. My problem is that time interprets "1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null" which are part of command like part of time, so I have no output.

Example (command I want to execute is more complex):

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" -p ls 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

So I'd like to know if there's a way to isolate the command from time command, just need execution time, not other information required from command output I'm measuring execution time.

I know it can be measured with this small piece of code.

```
start=`date +%s`
command
end=`date +%s`
runtime=$((end-start))
```

But just have doubt if it could be done with **time** command in a native way I don't know.

Comment: Is your shell really bash? (If so, you have a built-in version of `time` available, should you choose not to use the `/usr/bin/time` one).

Comment: ...which is to say, you can run `time { ls >/dev/null 2>&1; }` in bash, if you leave out the `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it independently on the shell is:

```
/bin/time -o my_file.txt my_command 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

or

```
/bin/time -o /dev/tty my_command 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Depends on which platform you're on; the MacOS `/usr/bin/time` doesn't have a `-o`.

Answer (score 0):

As given in [BashFAQ #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032), you can capture the output from the bash-builtin version of `time` (note that we're *not* using `/usr/bin/time` below):

```
{ time_result=$( { TIMEFORMAT='%R'; time ls 1>&3- 2>&4-; } 2>&1 ); } 3>&1 4>&2
```